# AdminDirectory.Members.list Authorization error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-admin-sdk

I'm experimenting with Admin SDK and trying to list Group Members in a Google Spreadsheet. Here's the code I've come up with:

```
function recordGroupsMembers() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Get all groups
  var groupPageToken, groupPage;
  do {
    groupPage = AdminDirectory.Groups.list({
      domain: 'mydomain.com',
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: groupPageToken
    });
    var groups = groupPage.groups;
    if (groups) {
      //Iterate groups
      for (var i in groups) {
        var group = groups[i];

        //Get members of group
        var membersPageToken, membersPage;
        do {
          membersPage = AdminDirectory.Members.list(group, {
            maxResults: 100,
            pageToken: membersPageToken
          });
          var members = membersPage.members;
          if (members) {
            //Iterate group members
            for (var j in members) {
              var member = members[j];
              Logger.log('%s member: %s', group.email, member.email);
            }
          } else {
            Logger.log('%s: no members.', group.email);
          }
          membersPageToken = membersPage.nextPageToken;  
        } while (membersPageToken);

      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No groups found.');
    }
    groupPageToken = groupPage.nextPageToken;
  } while (groupPageToken);

  ScriptProperties.setProperty('lastUpdate', new Date());
}
```

For the `AdminDirectory.Members.list` call, this error is shown:

> Not Authorized to access this resource/api

To be clear, the Admin SDK Directory Service has been [enabled](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) under **Resources > Advanced Google services…**, and in the Google Developer Console.

Also, the user running this script is able to successfully retrieve expected results using the API Explorer.

I get the impression I've either overlooked something *very* simple or there's a bug in the statement that "[Apps Script handles the authorization flow automatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, this script has two issues.

Not Authorized to access this resource/api  -> This has at least two possible causes:

```
a) You don't have sufficient Admin privileges to access this API (Basically, you're not a SuperAdmin).

b) The domain is spelled incorrectly in your live code (I hesitate to even mention this one, but mistakes do happen).
```

Otherwise, this part works fine for me 'As is' and I can only reproduce the:

```
Not Authorized to access this resource/api
```

when one of these two issues apply.

Once you resolve this error, you'll hit a 'Bad Request' for:

```
membersPage = AdminDirectory.Members.list(group, {
        maxResults: 100,
        pageToken: membersPageToken
      });
```

Around line 21.

This is because the line:

```
    var group = groups[i];
```

*Looks* like it's just returning a string with the name of the group, but in actually it's returning something like:

```
{id=GROUPID, nonEditableAliases=[GROUPEMAIL, GROUPEMAIL], etag=GROUPTAG, email=GROUPEMAIL, directMembersCount=3, description=, adminCreated=true, name=GROUPNAME, kind=admin#directory#group}
```

This is a simple fix, we just replace this with:

```
      membersPage = AdminDirectory.Members.list(group.email, {
        maxResults: 100,
        pageToken: membersPageToken
      });
```

And it will return the results we're looking for.

Comment: Thanks @hdcerberus , you put me on the right track. I had sufficient privileges but according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/list), `Admin.Members.list` requires a `groupKey` parameter which can be either the group's ID, email or an alias. I changed the line to:

`membersPage = AdminDirectory.Members.list(group.id, {maxResults: 100, pageToken: membersPageToken});`

…and all is well.