# How to get email delivery preferences in Google Groups

Tags: google-apps-script, google-groups

I am trying to use Google Apps Script to get the email delivery preference of members of a Google Group.  This code:

```
AdminDirectory.Members.list()
```

gets the group members but I do not see an email preference.  The info I am looking for is shown in the membership settings in groups.google.com.

Does anybody know how to get this in Apps Script?

Thanks for any tips or pointers

Comment: If you check the Apps Script documentation, the only thing that you can get is the email of the group by using the [`getEmail()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups/group#getEmail()) method. It will get this group's email address. 

For more information, check these SO question [27684315](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27684315) and [38784889](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38784889) on how to use `AdminDirectory.Members.list` in the Apps Script. You can verify here the only things that you can get by using this method.

Comment: Well, my code works fine and I can see the fields returned.  What I need is the missing "email preference" field (or whatever it is called).

Comment: I have the same question. @Scott: the field is called `delivery_settings` (shown [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members)).

Answer (score 0):

The [Members.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/list) method of the Admin Directory API does not return the `delivery_settings` field, but the [Members.get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/get) method does.

So after getting the array of group members, loop through the members and get each member's delivery setting:

```
for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {

  members[i]['delivery_settings'] = AdminDirectory.Members.get(groupEmail, members[i].email)['delivery_settings'];

}
```

Also, be aware that this has performance implications in Apps Script. `Members.list` is one API call, but `Members.get` will make another API call for each member of the group. This can cause your script to execute much slower if it runs on groups with a lot of members. You can monitor your script's performance using the [Execution Transcript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#execution_transcript).